# I like the effect of this/these normal(s), but I do not know how to recreate it

Tags: normals

I see that the vertex normals at the top are at a different looking angle than the rest. Every time I try to rotate normals it only rotates the split normals (pink). I am thinking if I can rotate the vertex normals (blue) instead, then maybe I can get this same effect. Am I on the right track?

[image]

Comment: I think vertex normals are always the average of the normals of the faces that meet the vertex. I don't think you can rotate them yourself. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure how to exactly recreate what you did, but what you have there looks like the result of _averaging_ the _normals_ by _face area_ on one or more of the thin faces around the edge(s).

Comment: @scurest I was thinking that it could be useful later on and save me a few vertices if I used it for the edges of a sci-fi door or the inside of the sliding door frame